# Can't rotate and change color of object on mouseclick on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mouseevent, glut

I tried to rotate around his own center an object when I click left button of the mouse but it doesn't seem to work...Also, when I right click the mouse I should change the color of the object but I don't understand why it doesn't seem to work, it just stops the rotation of the object..... Here it's my code that will help you, I added all the functions to see exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "dependente\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include "dependente\glfw\glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h> //incluziuni librarii

float ORG[3] = { 0,0,0 };
static GLfloat spin = 0.0;
GLfloat viewangle = 0, tippangle = 0, traj[120][3]; //variabila pentru unghi camera

GLfloat d[3] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 }; //vector directie

GLfloat  xAngle = 0.0, yAngle = 0.0, zAngle = 0.0;
bool draw_triangle = false; //variabila desenat figuri 
bool draw_square = false;
bool draw_decagon = false;

//  Use arrow keys to rotate entire scene !!!

void Special_Keys(int key, int x, int y) //functie ptr taste sus jos stanga dreapta
{
    switch (key) {

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  viewangle -= 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:  viewangle += 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:  tippangle -= 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  tippangle += 5;  break;

    default: printf("Special key %c == %d", key, key);
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void Triangle(void) //draw the triangle shape
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);//triangles have a common vertex, which is the central vertex
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //V0(red)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   //V1(green)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   //V2(blue)
    glEnd();
}
void Square(void) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f); // top left
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f); // top right 
    glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f); // bottom right
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f); // bottom left
    glEnd();
}
void Decagon(void) //draw the decagon shape
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.72f,0.8f, 0.0f); //a1
                glVertex3f(0.52f,   0.8f,0.0f);  //z
                glVertex3f(0.35f,   0.64f, 0.0f); //b1
                glVertex3f(0.3f,   0.48f, 0.0f); //d1
                glVertex3f(0.35f,   0.3f, 0.0f); //e1
                glVertex3f(0.52f, 0.16f, 0.0f); //l1
                glVertex3f(0.72f, 0.16f, 0.0f); //m1
                glVertex3f(0.9f, 0.3f, 0.0f); //o1
                glVertex3f(0.95f, 0.48f, 0.0f); //p1
                glVertex3f(0.9f, 0.64f, 0.0f); //c1
                glScalef(10, 10, 10);
                glTranslatef(1, 2, 3);
    glEnd();
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) //press a key to perform actions
{
    switch (key) {

    case 'd': d[0] += 0.1;  break; //camera right
    case 'a': d[0] -= 0.1;  break; //camera left
    case 'w': d[1] += 0.1;  break; //camera up 
    case 's': d[1] -= 0.1;  break; //camera down 
    case 'm': d[2] += 0.1;  break; //magnify
    case 'n': d[2] -= 0.1;  break; //minify
    case 't': draw_triangle = true; draw_decagon = false;   break; //draw pyramid when key is pressed
    case 'q': draw_square = true; draw_decagon = false; draw_triangle = false; break; //draw cube when key is pressed
    case 'l': draw_decagon = true; draw_triangle = false; break; //draw prism when key is pressed

    case 'x': xAngle += 5;  break; //modify x axis angle
    case 'y': yAngle += 5;  break; //modify y axis angle
    case 'z': zAngle += 5;  break;  //modify z axis angle

    default: printf("   Keyboard %c == %d", key, key); //see what key it's pressed
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void spinDisplay()
{
    spin = spin + 0.1;
    if (spin > 360.0)
    {
        spin = 0.0;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void mouse(int buton, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch (buton) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON: //here I don't know how to change the color of the shape
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
    default:glutIdleFunc(NULL);

        break;
    }
}
void redraw(void)
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);
    glRotatef(tippangle, 1, 0, 0);  // Up and down arrow keys 'tip' view.
    glRotatef(viewangle, 0, 1, 0);  // Right/left arrow keys 'turn' view.

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);


    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(d[0], d[1], d[2]);    // Move box down X axis.
    glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f); //increase the object size
    glRotatef(zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    glRotatef(yAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(xAngle, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if (draw_triangle)
        Triangle();

    if (draw_decagon)
        Decagon();
    if (draw_square)
        Square();

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 300);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutCreateWindow("Figure Rotation");
    glutDisplayFunc(redraw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(Special_Keys);

    glClearColor(0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);//specify which matrix is the current matrix, matrix that represents your camera's lens (aperture, far-field, near-field, etc).
    gluPerspective(60, 1.5, 1, 10); //set up a perspective projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //specify which matrix is the current matrix,matrix that represents your camera (position, pointing, and up vector).
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There isn't any call to the function `void mouse()` which is in the code.

Comment: Try not to multi-tag. Is this C or C++?

Comment: Yup, you probably just forgot to calls `glutMouseFunc` or whatever it's name is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so stupid..but now if I right click it doesn't change the color, it just stops the rotation

Comment: _if I right click it doesn't change the color, it just stops the rotation_ That's what I would expect from: `case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);`

Comment: Why are you including GLFW if you're using GLUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare a variable that represents the color of the shape. Like you do to change draw triangle or decagon.

Declare global variable:

```
bool colorChanged = false;
```

In mouse function change this variable, and add glutPostRedisplay call (otherwise the display funtion will not be called).

```
colorChanged = !colorChanged;
glutPostRedisplay();
```

When you render take into account this variable.

```
if (colorChanged) 
    glColor3f(0,0,0); 
else 
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
```

Be careful with this:

> ```
> glutMouseFunc(mouse);
> glutCreateWindow("Figure Rotation");
> ```

You are registering mouse function before creating the window. Some implementations ignore this call.